# Jersey REST service HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> return

Tags: jersey

I want to return object of type HashMap> in GET method using XML or JSON. On client side I get keys of map, but values are null.

This is return class:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getHashMap() {
    return hashMap;
}

public void setHashMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap) {
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
}
```

This is GET method in service:

```
@GET
@Path("/mapa")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Test mapa() {

    Test test = new Test();

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("first");
    list.add("second");

    hashMap.put("first", list);
    test.setHashMap(hashMap);

    return test;
}
```

I get this in browser:

```
<test>
  <hashMap>
    <entry>
      <key>first</key>
      <value/>
    </entry>
  </hashMap>
</test>
```

Why is value empty?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a Response instead of Test Class ?

```
@GET
@Path("/mapa")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response mapa() {

    Test test = new Test();

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("first");
    list.add("second");

    hashMap.put("first", list);
    test.setHashMap(hashMap);

    return Response.status(200).entity(test).build();
}
```

Comment: I tried this... the result is the same:

<pre>
XML response:
`<test>
   <hashMap>
      <entry>
         <key>first</key>
         <value/>
      </entry>
   </hashMap>
</test>`
</pre>

JSON response:
`{"hashMap":{"entry":{"key":"first","value":null}}}`

Comment: OK, so I think the default provider given by jersey for XML is not supporting this structure. I would advice you to write your custom provider and use Jackson to encode into JSON/XML your datas. See for provider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525510/jersey-produces-apache-xssfworkbook/11528260#11528260

Comment: Is there any other option that supports this structure?

Comment: I don't know, I'm using a custom JSON provider never tried XML